# beamer: no snm and out files

Tags: beamer

dear texperts:  does beamer have a "hook" that stops it from creating .snm, .out, and possibly .nav files?  I don't use the first two [they are all 0 bytes].  I know texshop can delete them and I can delete them by hand, but since I now have about 200 of these littered around, it would be nice to stick a "don't create" command into my beamer template.  /iaw

Comment: Do you know about [arara](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/arara)? You could set up `arara` rules in the preamble of your beamer tex files to delete the unneeded files at the end of each run. Of course, `arara` can do a whole lot more than just delete unneeded files at the end of a compilation...

Comment: not ideal.  I want to give the .tex file to others.  the ideal would be for beamer to open the files only when it writes the first time...